# NxNrwl shared custom form builder Library in Angular - Form Group and Nested FormGroups

Tags: angular, typescript, nrwl-nx

I wan to create a shared NxNrwl Angular Library. That will have all the FormGroups.

Customer Form

```
export abstract class CustomerForm {
  protected readonly _fb: FormBuilder;
  constructor() {
    this._fb = inject(FormBuilder);
  }

  public _createForm() {
    return this._fb.group({
      id: [''],
      name: [''],
      email: ['']
    });
  }
}
```

Product Form

```
export abstract class ProductForm {
  protected readonly _fb: FormBuilder;
  constructor() {
    this._fb = inject(FormBuilder);
  }

  public _createForm() {
    return this._fb.group({
      id: [''],
      name: [''],
      size: [''],
      color: ['']
    });
  }
}
```

My Idea:
There will only one shared library that will be responsible for all the formGroups and its validation at a central level.

Concern:
How to merge it?

```
export abstract class OrderForm {
      protected readonly _fb: FormBuilder;
      constructor() {
        this._fb = inject(FormBuilder);
      }
    
      public _createForm() {
        return this._fb.group({
          id: [''],
          date: [''],
          customer: ( here, how to add customer form ? )
          products: ( here, how to add FormArray of product ? )
        });
      }
    }
```